# Problem inserting PDF into LaTeX

Tags: graphics, windows

Okay so my MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{C:\Users\User\Documents\OU\LaTeX\TMA 02}}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\includegraphics{TMA 02 Q4a.pdf}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The error given by LaTeX is:

```
TMA 02.2.tex
76
Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@b ->C:\Users 
                       \User \Documents \OU \LaTeX \TMA 02
l.76 \includegraphics{TMA 02 Q4a.pdf}
```

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm really not sure where the problem lies. I've tried without using a graphics path, but I always get an error. The pdf is only 1 page and is, I believe, saved in the main directory, where the LaTeX file itself is saved.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use forward slashes instead of backslashes: `\graphicspath{{C:/Users/User/Documents/OU/LaTeX/TMA02}}` and avoid spaces in file and directory names.

Comment: @egreg Oh I missed slashes!.

Comment: for what `enumerate` is used here?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{grffile}` before `\usepackage{graphicx}` to use file names with spaces...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Better: don't use spaces in file or directory names....